# In Android, how to get a scrollpane

Tags: android

I am wondering if there is a widget that acts like a ScrollPane in Swing.

Actually, I am trying to make a layout, where the top has the title bar always visible, and under it have a variable height component that I can scroll vertically, (while leaving the title bar visible)

I am sure this is quite easy but I am not seeing it

Thanks, Victor

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you want to wrap your scrollable component(s) or layout in a `ScrollView`.
Keep the "always visible" components out of it, and you'll achieve your desired effect.

[API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html)

[How to use it](http://android-pro.blogspot.com/2010/02/android-scrollview.html)

[Some tricks to use it](http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/08/15/scrollviews-handy-trick/)