# Preventing elements of a layout from overlapping

Tags: android, xml

When i type long text in the last EditText(opedt),it overlaps the button at the bottom. The text gets on top of the button. I want the text to stop just before reaching the button and scrolls. How to  go about it?

here is my layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="mpack.gt.UnityActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/finirbtn"
        android:background="#008000"
        android:id="@+id/validerreponsebtn"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/opmtxt"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/opmtxt"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/opdesc"
        android:layout_below="@+id/opmtxt"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/repopmstxt"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/repopmtxt"
        android:layout_below="@+id/opdesc"
        />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/opreponseedt"
        android:layout_below="@+id/repopmtxt"
        android:hint="@string/hintreponse"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Use scroll. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058209/in-android-how-to-get-a-scrollpane

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent elements from overlapping you should not use `RelativeLayout` in first place, but choose other layouts that does not allow children Views to overlap. `RelativeLayout` allows you to do so, so whenver text view grows, it will not expand like i.e. `LinearLayout` would do (unless child needs more space that the whole layout takes)

Comment: how do i have the ordering of my elements? i want the button to be at the bottom and the others at the top.

Comment: You may want to wrap some elements in additional layouts and then group it together. There is no limitation and you can safely put i.e. two vertical linear layouts in one horizontal layout etc. My advice is - make it look and work as you want. Then optimize overdraws etc. So if wrapping some elements in other separate layout would help - do that

Answer (score 0):

One way is to set `Button` below last EditText instead of align to the bottom.

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/finirbtn"
        android:background="#008000"
        android:id="@+id/opreponseedt"
        android:layout_below="@+id/opdesc"/>
```

Comment: i want the button to be at the bottom

Comment: It will be at the bottom, just not still to the bottom. Otherwise you can use LinearLayout instead of RelativeLayout.